# Find into model by key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to obtain a "row" from a model querying by key. ¿How can I achieve that?
I´m looking for something like

{{ mysettings.backcolor | searchby(datuak.ref) }} or something like this.

The fact is that I have a model with data, and other model with bacground and forecolor info. The relation between them is the "ref" column.

When printing the table, on the ng-repeat, I want to to obtain the foreground/backcolor querying it by id.

Any help or clue?

I have this two models in my controller:

```
$scope.mysettings = [
      { ref: '3CI00001', backcolor: '#000000', forecolor: '#ffffff' },
      { ref: '3CI00002', backcolor: '#5cb85c', forecolor: '#000000' }
    ];
```

And this is the other model:

```
$scope.datuak = [
      {
        linea: '1',
        egunak:[{
          fetxa: '2014/05/19',
            turnoak: [
            { 
              turno: "1", 
              ordenes: [
                { ref: '3CI00001'},
                { of: 'OF000013'}
              ]  
            },
            { 
              turno: "2", 
              ordenes: [
                { ref:'3CI00001'},
                { of:'112233'},
                { ref:'3CI00001'}
              ]
            },
            {
              turno: "3",
              ordenes: [
                { ref:'3CI00001'}
              ]
            }
            ]},
          {fetxa: '2014/05/20'},
          {fetxa: '2014/05/21',
            turnoak: [
            { 
              turno: "1", 
              ordenes: [
                { ref: '3CI00001'},
                { of: 'OF200013'}
              ]  
            },
            { 
              turno: "2", 
              ordenes: [
                { ref:'3CI00001'},
                { of:'OF232233'},
                { of:'OF289977'}
              ]
            },
            {
              turno: "3",
              ordenes: [
                { ref:'3CI00001'},
                { of:'OF200000'},
                { ref:'3CI00001'},
                { of:'OF200000'},
                { ref:'3CI00001'}
              ]
            }
          ]},
          {fetxa: '2014/05/22'},
          {fetxa: '2014/05/23'},
          {fetxa: '2014/05/24'},
          {fetxa: '2014/05/25'}
        ]
      },
      {
        linea: '2',
        egunak:[
          { fetxa: '2014/05/19'},
          {
          fetxa: '2014/05/20',
            turnoak: [
            { 
              turno: "1", 
              ordenes: [
                { ref: '3CI00001'},
                { of: '2OF000013'}
              ]  
            },
            { 
              turno: "2", 
              ordenes: [
                { ref:'3CI00001'},
                { of:'2OF2233'},
                { ref:'3CI00001'}
              ]
            },
            {
              turno: "3",
              ordenes: [
                { ref:'3CI00001'}
              ]
            }
          ]},
          {fetxa: '2014/05/21'},
          {
          fetxa: '2014/05/22',
            turnoak: [
            { 
              turno: "1", 
              ordenes: [
                { ref: '3CI00001'},
                { of: '2OF200013'}
              ]  
            },
            { 
              turno: "2", 
              ordenes: [
                { ref:'3CI00001'},
                { of:'2OF232233'},
                { ref:'3CI00001'}
              ]
            },
            {
              turno: "3",
              ordenes: [
                { ref:'3CI00001'},
                { of:'2OF200000'},
                { ref:'3CI00001'},
                { of:'2OF200000'},
                { ref:'3CI00001'}
              ]
            }
          ]},
          {fetxa: '2014/05/23'},
          {fetxa: '2014/05/24'},
          {fetxa: '2014/05/25'}
        ]
      }
    ];
```

With this two model, I have my view like this:

```
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="lineas in datuak">
            <td class="tdlinea">Linea:{{ lineas.linea }}</td>
            <td data-ng-repeat="nireindex in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]">
              <table class="table text-center table-condensed">
                <thead>
                  <th>Mañana</th>
                  <th>Tarde</th>
                  <th>Noche</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table>
                          <tr ng-repeat="orden in lineas.egunak[nireindex].turnoak[0].ordenes" ng-if="checkStatus(lineas.egunak[nireindex].fetxa,nireindex)">
                            <td>{{ orden.ref }} {{ orden.of }}   </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <table>
                          <tr ng-repeat="orden in lineas.egunak[nireindex].turnoak[1].ordenes" ng-if="checkStatus(lineas.egunak[nireindex].fetxa,nireindex)"><td>{{ orden.ref }} {{ orden.of }}</td></tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <table>
                          <tr ng-repeat="orden in lineas.egunak[nireindex].turnoak[2].ordenes" ng-if="checkStatus(lineas.egunak[nireindex].fetxa,nireindex)"><td>{{ orden.ref }} {{ orden.of }}</td></tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>                             
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr> <!-- lineas -->
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look at angular js filter *filter* : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

if you need to go further you can create your own that use array.filter() method:

```
app.filter('searchBy', function() {
    return function( array, prop , val ) {
         // filter has polyfills for older browsers. Check underscore.js if needed
         return array.filter( function(row) {
             return row[prop] == val;
         } );
         // this returns an array. You can pick the first element with [0]
    }
} );
```

then use it in your loop like this:

```
{{ mySetting | searchBy : 'ref' : linea.ref }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to achieve this is to refactor your model to behave like an associative array instead of a common. It should end up like this:

```
$scope.mysettings = {
  3CI00001: { ref: '3CI00001', backcolor: '#000000', forecolor: '#ffffff' },
  3CI00002: { ref: '3CI00002', backcolor: '#5cb85c', forecolor: '#000000' }
};
```

That way you could access objects by it's id simply by doing mysettings[id].backcolor

Cheers!

Comment: but how can you comlete the sentence? {{ mysettings{orden.ref}.backcolor }} ?

Comment: {{mysettings[order.ref].backcolor}}

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is loop through your settings, then loop through each settings object and return the matched item:

```
function findSetting(s) {

   //loop through all settings-->
   for (var i = 0; i < mySettings.length; i++) {

       //if setting is an object loop through keys in object-->
       if (typeof (mySettings[i]) === 'object') {

           for (var key in mySettings[i]) {
               if (mySettings[i][key] === s) {

                   //return match-->
                   return mySettings[i];
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/LWFbd/) is a fiddle